# Java.Random Wrap Around

Tags: java

I've found multiple references saying that the Java.Random PRNG will wrap around after 2^48 numbers have been issues. Has anyone actually tested this with code and determined when it wraps around?

Thanks

Comment: Can you cite the references you mention?

Comment: George Marsaglias paper on the XorShift algorithm is quite approachable, and describes simple implementations of PRNGs with periods of up to 2^128-1, in case you need that. It's also very fast.

Comment: Why does this matter to you?

Comment: This is one of those questions that - regardless of the answer (yes or no) - has, or should have, little influence on any decisions.  To wit: the limitations are spelled out, and establish an effective lower-bound. At worst, if you question those limitations, the *real* limitations are worse.. at best maybe better.  Regardless, the key issue is that 2^48 "isn't good enough" for cryptographic work - so if you have *any* concerns go find a better alternative.  If it doesn't matter.. then it doesn't matter.  Make your decision accordingly.

Comment: What I'm asking is the sentence with the question mark at the end. "Has anyone actually tested this with code and determined when it wraps around?" Doed this make it clearer?

Comment: Richard, I’m curious why you need to have such a callous attitude? I’m studying and learning about implementations of PRNG and Java is a common one. There are a lot of people around here that are knowledgeable and helpful with their knowledge. So I asked if anyone had tested the limitations. Why does that draw your ire of the question has “little influence.” I’m sorry I couldn’t ask a question that reached up to your standards of influence.

Answer (score 8):

Well, Java `Random` is [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with a 48-bit seed. This is laid out in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html/):

> The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.2.1.)

There is no need to test it. LCG's are *very* well understood. Knuth actually does lay it out very well in TAOCP Volume 2 (it's some of the most readable material in all of his books).

The multiplier for the LCG in Java is known to be 25214903917 and we understand *that* generator very well. What Java does is it takes bits 16 through 47 of the output of that LCG to produce the 32-bit output. It does this because it is known that the low-order bits have shorter periods than the high-order bits.

Comment: +1 Technically it generates 32-bit values and if you do nextInt(2) it should wrap after 32 * 2^48 numbers.

Comment: "There is no need to test it." Fateful words when used around software implementation, hahaha

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok, just catching comments here.  Bernie, in another "answer" suggests he's seeing a wrap around at 32*2^43 = 2^48.  Would you be able to reconcile that with your 32*2^48?  I'm just curious now... ty.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: That's impossible. There are only 48-bits of output. Given an output `xi = x`, if we *ever* see `xj = x` again, then the *next* iteration in both cases are `axi + b mod m` and `axj + b mod` which are equal since `xi` equals `xj`; at this point, the sequence is doomed to repeat. The mask applied to the 48-bits doesn't change anything because the position of the mask doesn't change (it's the high 32-bits). This shows that the period is at most the number of 48-bit bit patterns, or, `2^48`.